# Unable to Set Up SAML SSO on AS 5.1.0

Tags: wso2, saml

I have set up an instance of AS 5.1.0 to perform SAML SSO with an instance of IS 4.1.0.  When I connect to the AS Management Console, I get forwarded to the SAML SSO login page on the IS instance.  After entering my credentials I am forwarded back to the AS instance where I receive a page indicating that the login failed.

In the AS server's log, I see that an exception was thrown: org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticatorException: Error occured while processing saml2 response

This message is preceded by: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.util.Util} -  Content is not allowed in prolog.

If I do not use SAML SSO, I can log in to both Management Consoles without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue[1] and this will be fixed soon. After fixing the issue, a public patch will be available and attached to the jira.

[1]. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1043

Comment: Until then, I have switched to running IS 4.0.0 and AS 5.0.1 and they seem to be behaving properly for SAML SSO.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered something similar to this issue... Can you try the SSO configuration as shown in the image (with "Response Signing") and check whether it solves your issue...
[image]

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: I had enabled assertion signing rather than response signing.  Changing it to match your screen shot did not change anything.